# Can I get a list of files marked --assume-unchanged?

Tags: git

What have I marked as `--assume-unchanged`? Is there any way to find out what I've tucked away using that option?

I've dug through the `.git/` directory and don't see anything that looks like what I'd expect, but it must be somewhere. I've forgotten what I marked this way a few weeks ago and now I need to document those details for future developers.

Answer (score 523, accepted):

You can use [`git ls-files -v`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).  If the character printed is lower-case, the file is marked assume-unchanged.

To print just the files that are unchanged use:

```
git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'
```

To embrace your lazy programmer, turn this into a [git alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases). Edit your `.gitconfig` file to add this snippet:

```
[alias]
    ignored = !git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]"
```

Now typing `git ignored` will give you output like this:

```
h path/to/ignored.file
h another/ignored.file
```

Comment: Ah ha! Now _that's_ what I was looking for. Thanks, Andrew. A quick alias/script should make it easy to retrieve a list limited to those files.

Comment: git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]

Comment: My OS apparently has a weird collation setup, so Matt's command didn't work for me.  Here's what I added under the `[alias]` section of my `.gitconfig`:
`ignored = !git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]"`

Comment: Weird, yes, [a-z] has stopped working for me too! Abe's [[:lower]] does the job.

Comment: The reason [a-z] doesn't work is that the shell expands it as a wildcard; if the current directory contains a file that matches that pattern (ie a single lowercase letter), then the expansion of that is the name of the file. Try adding quotes, eg "[a-z]"

Comment: @DomQ: No, that's not the (only) reason. I have the same problem, even with quotes: `grep  '^[a-z]'`. The problem is indeed caused by the collation setup. I get this with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. With `LANG` unset or set to `C`, `[a-z]` works as expected.

Comment: git ls-files -v | grep -e "^[a-z]"

Comment: The suggested aliases work for finding unchanged files at the current directory and below. If you want a list of all "assume-unchanged" files in the repository, you'll need `git ls-files -v \`git rev-parse --show-toplevel\` | grep "^[a-z]"`

Comment: I couldn't get the default Mac OS X `grep` to work, what worked for me was using `egrep` instead.

`git ls-files -v | egrep "^[a-z]"`

Comment: output just file names: `git ls-files -v | awk '$1~/[a-z]/{sub(/([^ ]* )/,"");print}'`

Comment: @caiguanhao, my version to output only name: `git ls-files -v | grep "^[[:lower:]]" | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: I would call the alias `hide` or `show-hidden` than `ignored`, since `ignore` may mean the ignored files defined in `.gitignore`

Comment: I don't really like this solution as for "skip-worktree" files, it is an uppercase S. :/

Answer (score 92):

#### One Liner

```
git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]"
```

#### Use Aliases

IMHO, `git hidden` is better for files marked as `--assume-unchanged`:

```
git config --global alias.hidden '!git ls-files -v | grep "^[a-z]"'
```

Here's a list of related aliases I have in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
  hide = update-index --assume-unchanged
  unhide = update-index --no-assume-unchanged
  unhide-all = update-index --really-refresh
  hidden = !git ls-files -v | grep \"^[a-z]\"
  ignored = !git status -s --ignored | grep \"^!!\"
```

To make it work in **subdirectories** and support **arguments**:

```
  hidden = "!f(){ git -C \"$GIT_PREFIX\" ls-files -v \"$@\" | grep \"^[a-z]\";}; f"
  ignored = "!f(){ git -C \"$GIT_PREFIX\" status -s --ignored \"$@\" | grep \"^!!\";}; f"
```

For example:

```
 # cd target
 # git ignored classes
```

#### About File Status

For me most *hidden* files are marked with flag `h`, though there're actually several other flags according to the manual of `git-ls-files`**`-v`**:

> ```
> -v
>     Similar to -t, but use lowercase letters for files that are 
> marked as assume unchanged (see git-update-index(1)).
> ```

About `git ls-files`**`-t`**:

> ```
> This option (-t) identifies the file status with the following tags 
> (followed by a space) at the start of each line:
>
> H   cached
> S   skip-worktree
> M   unmerged
> R   removed/deleted
> C   modified/changed
> K   to be killed
> ?   other
> ```

Comment: Nice easy-to-remember aliases :) Thanks

Comment: Here are some more flexible variants:
`hidden = "!f() { git ls-files -v \"$@\" | grep \"^[a-z]\"; }; f"` and `ignored = "!f() { git status -s --ignored \"$@\" | grep \"^!!\"; }; f"`. This allows, for example, `git ignored -- PATH1 PATH2` to only list ignored files in certain paths (useful when you have a lot of ignored files).

Comment: Thank you for alias

Answer (score 30):

This command works more consistently for me.  It will print only the files that are listed as 'assume-unchanged'.

```
git ls-files -v|grep "^h"
```

I've used this lots of times in different environments and it works perfectly.

Comment: In the Windows prompt, use `grep "^h"` instead of single quotes

Answer (score 12):

**Windows command line** solution using **findstr**:

```
git ls-files -v | findstr /B h
```

Answer (score 9):

PowerShell solution, using **Select-String \ sls**

```
git ls-files -v | sls -pattern ^h -casesensitive
```