# Leiningen 'lein install' without writing pom.xml?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I've been contributing to a project in which there's a fixed pom.xml, but I tend to modify project.clj, temporarily, for various purposes.  Most of the time, Leiningen seems to ignore pom.xml, but `lein install` and `lein deploy` rewrite pom.xml.  Is this necessary to Leiningen's functioning?  If not, can I stop it? Haven't found anything about this in the online docs yet.

It's not a big problem, but I'd rather not deal with having to restore the official pom.xml in my project before doing a 'git commit', for example.

EDIT: I discovered a solution for my situation, which is to [create a 'checkouts' directory with a link to the other project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies).  This causes the other project to be pulled in, without creating a new jar.  However, I'm still curious: Does Leiningen need to create pom.xml e.g. for `lein install`?  Why?  I'd like to understand the process.

Comment: Lately I've been using a different solution.  Assuming the project uses git: First I make sure that all changes are committed or stashed.  Then I do `lein install` followed by `git stash`.  The only file that's changed by `lein install` is pom.xml.  `git stash` undoes the changes made by `lein install`.  (Then I change project.clj in the other project to reflect the new version number of the one I just installed, if that version number changed.)  This process is a kludge, but I find it causes fewer complications than the checkouts method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of whether `lein install` can be run without generating a pom.xml.

The reason it generates a pom is that **leiningen uses maven** to grab all the dependencies. In fact, maven is able to get dependencies from clojars and leiningen uses it for the clojure dependencies as well as the java ones. **Maven requires a pom.xml** to specify repository locations and other configuration necessary to run javac (or any other build commands) in addition to a groupId and artifactId to deploy your library to a (potentially local) repository

---

Another possible workaround to your issue is to use changelists (specifically, if using tortoiseSVN, I'd use the ignore-on-commit changelist) to ignore your pom.xml in most situations commitwise. I believe [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24396192/2039914) may assist you with how to do that in git.