# git how to switch branches without committing your changes

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I am working in a branchX and it has a dozen config files that I do not want to commit. So i marked all the config files as --skip-worktree.  Now I want to change to branchY.  How do I do it?

I tried

```
git checkout branchY
```

and it says

```
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
```

So i tried to stash them, using

```
git stash save
```

but it says

```
No local changes to save
```

This is ***very annoying***.  Apparently the only solution is

1. use `git ls-files -v` to get a list of all the skip-worktree files
2. for each file, remove the skip-worktree
3. `git stash save`
4. `git checkout branchY`
5. `git stash pop`
6. manually resolve any conflict with `--theirs`
7. for each file, add the skip-worktree flag again

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Did you try ignoring them (with .gitignore) instead?

Comment: @Edmundo that would work if the config files were not already versioned, which they are.  Basically the master has a set of config files for production, but locally I make changes to them because my development environment is a little different.

Comment: When a file is already versioned and I want to "ignore" it, I've always used ```git update-index --assume-unchanged``` on said file and I've never hit problems when switching (understanding that I actually do not care if the files are modified in my local so that git can do as it pleases with them if I check out anything).

Comment: The easiest way, by far, is to *not commit configuration files* (at least not in the corresponding source—it's fine to have them committed in a separate repository meant just for tracking "my config files" or "my foo-system configuration"). Anything else leads to the kind of head- and/or heart- and/or stomach-ache you are experiencing now. That said, consider using `git worktree add` to work on another branch in a separate work-tree with a separate index; this may suffice and avoid all the aches.

Comment: @Edmundo, i've tried `assume-unchanged` and it also prevents me from changing branches. Perhaps it worked for you because you did not actually change the files? But I need to change the config files. The checkout fails because it notices the config were changed, even though I tell it they are assume-unchanged.

Comment: @Edmundo `skip-worktree` is the better solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/1615903

Comment: @JohnHenckel this happens because the config files have different contents in the branch you are switching to - what would you expect git to do in this situation?

Comment: @1615903 The purpose of skip-worktree is so that developers can make any file exempt from git. Any git command that might alter the file should simply skip over it. If I do a checkout, then git should skip those files. In other words, git checkout should succeed, but not make any changes to the skipped files. This is how skip-worktree should have been implemented. What do you think it the purpose of skip-worktree?The current implementation seems useless to me.

Comment: I was commenting on Edmundo's suggestion to use `assume-unchanged`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `git 1.9.1` and it is possible to switch branches with changes in a file that's already in the tree and then skipped with `git update-index --skip-worktree filename`.

The file is not changed after the switch (i.e. it is not changed to the version in the branch I switched to).

*(I would have thought that this is the behavior since 1.7.7 since its release notes state `* "git stash" learned an "--include-untracked option".` but 1.7.7 was released before you asked the question, so I don't know.)*

Please note that when trying to switch to a branch that doesn't have the file git still complains with

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
>           f1.config