# Is there a Git equivalent to SVN's ignore-on-commit?

Tags: git, svn

In SVN, it is possible to add versioned files to a special change list called *ignore-on-commit*.

The effect is that the files will not be included in commits by default, unless they are explicitly selected (e.g. in a graphical client where files to commit have to be selected with checkmarks) even when they are changed.

I have already found that the general "change list" feature [does not exist the same way in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606809/git-equivalence-of-svn-changelist), but here, I am rather looking for something more specific. I am not asking for general change lists, but for a way to mark certain *versioned* files as exempt from commits by default, possibly even to the extent that when switching/merging, those files are automatically reverted.

Comment: I shudder to think how much would need to change in order to support this.

Comment: @Guildenstern: I'm not sure what you mean. Surely, this could be scripted - store the paths/patterns of files thusly-excluded somewhere, revert them right before a commit, commit, then apply the local changes again. Sounds pretty straightforward, but of course, if it's not somehow supported out of the box, we'll rather find some other way.

Comment: You ask if there is a Git equivalent (i.e. that Git itself supports this). I say that I shudder to think what it would take to support this, meaning how much Git itself would need to change in order to support this. That’s not about scripting around the issue since you didn’t ask about scripting around the issue.

Comment: @Guildenstern: If scripting around the issue seems sufficiently straightforward, then the answer to "how much Git itself would need to change in order to support this" is "Very little". Or am I imagining this too simply? In any case, scripting around the issue is not the way I'm actually going to use, I still have an alternative solution in mind now that I know this way is not supported directly by Git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking is, in general, a question about how to ignore changes to tracked files, [which the Git FAQ is clear that Git doesn't support](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  The FAQ is also clear that some people try to suggest approaches which don't work and you shouldn't use:

> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

If your goal is to work with things like configuration files, the FAQ proposes a solution:

> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

Comment: "which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate" - this is precisely what I'm seeking to avoid. The codebase from the repo must be good to go (in my case, compile) without any mandatory copying around of file templates. However, I'll accept this answer as it states there is no good way with GIt, which for me means I will integrate the generation of these files in a scripting step that has to be run (automatically) before compilation anyway.