# I ran git update-index --assume-unchanged and now want to get the list of files?

Tags: git, git-index

I temporarily wanted to get rid of some files for a certain commit and ran: `git update-index --assume-unchanged file_name` on a bunch of files.

Then I closed my terminal, is there anyway of getting back the names of files that I ran the `git update-index` command on so that I can run the `--not-assume-unchanged` on them?

Comment: I don't know the answer, however next time use the staging area instead, it's more usable and specially designed for this use. `update-index` is plumbing and difficult to use for non-gurus

Comment: Looks like this question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to further extend Richard Michael's answer, you can simply grep for a lowercase letter at the beginning of the line of the ls-files -v output

```
git ls-files -v|grep ^[a-z]
```

will show you just your assumed-unchanged files

Answer (score 3):

Just run it on all the files in your tree. The default is to not assume unchanged.

Why did you run it in the first place? If you want to exclude files from a commit, just `git add` the files you want manually and run `git commit`. You only get all modified files if you pass the `-a` flag to `git commit`, so just don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Note, I am using `git --version` 1.8.1.2.

You may determine the bits set for files in the index with: `git ls-files -v`.  Files with `assume-unchanged` bit set have *lowercase* tags.

Do not confuse this with the tag `S`, which corresponds to the `skip-worktree` bit (which would appear as `s` if the file *also* had the `assume-unchanged` bit set).

See `git help update-index` and the discussion about the tags themselves in the `-t` and `-v` option sections.

For example: `Gemfile` has `skip-worktree` **set**, we'll also set `assume-unchanged`.

```
$ git ls-files -v|grep Gemfile
S Gemfile
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile
$ git ls-files -v|grep Gemfile
s Gemfile
```