# Command to tell git to not track certain files

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-add, git-status

I know there is a shortcut for this, and cannot remember it.

I am working in a repository, and have about 8 files I need to add and commit, and 2 that are modified, that I do not need to commit. Rather than running `git add <file>` for each file I'm committing, I would like to run 2 commands to ignore the files I do not need to add, and then run `git add .`  for the 8 I am adding/committing.

I thought the command to ignore the files I don't need was `git checkout -- <file I don't need>`, but I keep getting the error that `pathspec 'file I don't need' did not match any file(s) known to git`

I thought, of course, it's because those 2 files are still untracked. So I added everything with `git add .`  and THEN ran `git checkout -- <file I don't need>`. However, when I run a `git status` after that,  those files still show up to be committed.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442130/git-temporarily-ignore-trivial-changes-to-files

Comment: No, it definitely wasn't any of the commands outlined there. I really could have sworn it was git checkout -- <filename>. I could give some of those a try, though!

Comment: Here's another: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351856/1264804

Answer (score 0):

To take files which are staged out of the staging area, use `git reset` :

```
git reset -- file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought, of course, it's because those 2 files are still untracked.

If this is the case, perhaps what you want is `git add -u` or `git add -u .`.  This is very different from `git add .`, since `-u` means *update*.  One must then ask the obvious question: *update **what?***  This is answered in [the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> `-u`, `--update`
>       Update the index just where it
> already has an entry matching <pathspec>. This removes as well
> as modifies index entries to match the working tree, but adds no
> new files.
>
> If no <pathspec> is given when `-u` option is used, all
> tracked files in the entire working tree are updated (old
> versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory
> and its subdirectories).

So that's the answer: `-u` means *update Git's index*.  The index is also known as the *staging area*, and it holds a copy of every file, ready to be committed, in exactly the form that Git will use when making the next commit.  Updating the index therefore updates the proposed next commit.

Note that if some file exists in Git's index, but you have *removed* it from your working tree, `git add -u` will *remove* the file from Git's index.  That is, the proposed next commit now also lacks the file, just like the working tree.  Once you've done this, a later `git add -u` won't *re-add* the file, as it's already absent from Git's index.  You'd need a non-`-u` `git add` to put the file into Git's index, so that `git add -u` will notice if the working tree copy has been modified since then, and pick up the new file content.

The parenthetical remark about old versions of Git is describing how `git add -u` (with no files listed) worked in Git version 1.x.  The new 2.x behavior examines places above the current working directory; to get the Git 1.x behavior, use `git add -u .`.  This works because `.` means *the current working directory and all subdirectories*, which is of course how Git 1.x interpreted a bare `git add -u`.