# Git: List all files with assume-unchanged flag

Tags: git

I need the assume-unchanged flag to avoid wrong commits of my project settings files. I do this via:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

There is also a way to disable this with --no-assume-unchanged.

Now I added 5 files in this way and subsequently decided to add some of them again with the counter-flag.

Is there a way to list all these files declared as "assume-unchanged"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the lower-level command `ls-files`:

```
% git ls-files -v
h a.txt
H b.txt
```

If the first character is lowercase, it is marked as "assume unchanged", in this case `a.txt`. See also the [man page of ls-files](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

Comment: or even better: git ls-files -v | egrep -r "^h .*" Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page of [`git update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) :

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use git ls-files -v.

And according to the man page of [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) :

> -v
>
> [...] use lowercase letters for files that are marked as assume unchanged

So in order to get all files marked as assumed unchanged use :

```
ls-files -v | egrep -r "^[a-z] .*"
```