# Rails Simple Blogger Heroku App: Precompiling Assets Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have tried everything in the book it feels, yet I keep getting the same error.
Surprisingly, I have  not found this exact error anywhere else.

```sh
remote:        error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/tmp/build_0e5b0c14c98db4a63ddfc87fc6d11490"
```

[Here is the full error on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/MZX1XRAZ)

[Here is the repository for the (rather simple) blogger project](https://github.com/Eduardo06sp/blogger)

I even tried running `rake assets:precompile` locally and run into absolutely no errors.
I ran `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`, pushed to my repo then tried to deploy, nothing.

I *raked* through tons of StackOverflow questions and tried googling my error, giving every edit/command I came across a try, but no luck.

**EDIT:** The following are the contents of my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "blogger",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: In rails 6 there is a package.json file in the app directory. It is finding that file.

Comment: I updated my post with the contents of my package.json file, I'm not sure what's wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My package.json file was not present in my Github repository, although it *does* exist in my local system.

I had no pending files to be committed and my .gitignore shows no exclusion of any json files.
I'm not sure *why* it wasn't uploaded to my repository.

**So I had to force add it to the staging area by running:
`git add -f path/to/the/file` (credit to [@San's answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993082/why-doesnt-git-recognize-that-my-file-has-been-changed-therefore-git-add-not-w#comment72104756_24316479)).**

Then I simply committed the change and pushed to Heroku successfully!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Basic configuration for Rails 6 :-

Run `yarn install`, or just `yarn`. It will create a package.json file :-

**`package.json'**

This file contain necessary packages for your webpack.

For more references read :-

[#yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/#toc-managed-by-yarn)

[#webpacker](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/2612fa987b9f9ed7cb53a88fcba247b3#webpack-without-webpacker-in-rails-app)

And also if you want to precompile in production environment change the config in below file :-

```
config/webpacker.yml

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile:true ## just make this compile true

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

then execute commands :-

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber 
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I followed your steps, but I already had a package.json file for my app. 
I updated my post to display its contents. 
It gives me the same exact error regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! :}

Comment: But in your git repository there is no package.json file.

Comment: Do I need to upload it? It's not in my .gitignore or anything.
https://i.postimg.cc/VNNQwVmh/Screenshot-2019-12-28-23-11-34.png

Comment: Above is mine project repo screenshot you have to do the same thing push your package.json file also.. Because in error you can clearly se that heroku is finding for package.json file.. thanks and also you upvote my answer..it cost you nothing :)