# Folder getting ignored in GIT without its presence in .gitignore

Tags: git

I have a .net core project with wwwroot folder in it. So in another angular project, on ng build I am outputing the compiled files into wwwroot folder. But when trying to check status

```
git status
```

it is not considering the wwwroot folder at all. Every other changes being shown.

I checked in .gitignore folder and there is no entry to ignore that folder. So what could be failing here?

Comment: type `ls -la` in `bash` and  make sure wwwroot/ is in the same root as .git/

Comment: checkout this answer <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993082/why-doesnt-git-recognize-that-my-file-has-been-changed-therefore-git-add-not-w/24316479>

Comment: Check the global and user gitignore as well!

Comment: @PeymanMajidi As the answer suggested I tried clearing the git cache which now solved the issue..  Thanks a lot for pointing that..