# Exception clause for file name in .gitignore | Git

Tags: git, git-push

`cat .gitignore`:

```
...
*log
...
```

I wanted to ignore all `.log` files, except now for `cli.log`. How can I make this an exception?

---

Original Problem

"1 Pushed file isn't in remote repo, but all other files of same commit do | Git"

I have been successful at pushing changes to files... except `cli.log`.

I have tried solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16993082/why-doesnt-git-recognize-that-my-file-has-been-changed-therefore-git-add-not-w) with no luck.

**Terminal:**

```
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/.../data_simulator$ git checkout simulate_data
Already on 'simulate_data'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/simulate_data'.
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/.../data_simulator$ git pull
Already up to date.
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/.../data_simulator$ cd data
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/.../data_simulator/data$ ls
Citizenship.csv  cli.log  currency_symbols_map.json
me@LAPTOP-G1DAPU88:~/.ssh/.../data_simulator/data$
```

**Git:**

```
data_simulator/data:
    Citizenship.csv
    currency_symbols_map.json
```

Comment: Check `.gitignore` for patterns that would match, such as `*.log`?

Comment: `cd ..` a few times, `cat .gitignore`. 1 line says `*.log`. How do I make an exception for the name of my file `cli.log`; and ignore every other `.log` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ignore+all+file+type+except

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you. Can one of you "accept" the suggest post as the answer at all?

Comment: There is actually no need for you to add anything in `.gitignore` for that file. Just ignore all `.log` files, and add **with force** the file. And that's it.

Comment: @eftshift0: that method does work, but I generally dislike it on a sort of procedural or categorization basis: I think that `.gitignore` should work correctly if you accidentally run `git rm --cached -rf .`, then realize that was a mistake and run `git add .`. Force-adding one file to bypass `.gitignore` means that this "repair my mistake" trick wouldn't work.

Comment: Makes sense.... but you do check `git status` before committing, right? XD You should be able to see that the file is showing up as deleted in that case (after adding everything back).

Comment: Interesting pointers guys. Thank you for the knowledge share