# Git not detecting change to file overwritten in Jenkins Powershell script

Tags: git, powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that is checking out a repository, compiling a C project, and then is supposed to stage, commit and push the generated binaries. However, the job fails at staging/committing the binaries because it does not detect any changes and therefore has nothing to commit.

In the PowerShell script that does the compilation, after the binary image is created I copy it to another directory where it is tracked in our repository.

**Source binary file:** 
*.\device_test\images\Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.0.img*

**Destination binary file (the one that is tracked):** 
*.\device_platforms\nordic15_2\device_device\device_out\ROYAL_FW_40.04.10.0.bin*

Despite the destination binary file showing an updated LastWriteTime before and after being overwritten, `git status` does not show that file as modified and `git add -f binaryfile` does nothing.

```
Build #1
    Copying version header...
    Current FW version: #define DEVICE_FW_VERSION "40.04.10.0"
    Compiling .\device_platforms\nordic15_2\device_device\pca10100e\s112\arm5_no_packs\device.uvprojx...
        Keil build successful! image=.\device_platforms\nordic15_2\device_device\device_out\ROYAL_FW_40.04.10.0.bin
    Image pre-copy modified: 10/17/2022 12:35:44
    Copying image file .\device_platforms\nordic15_2\device_device\device_out\ROYAL_FW_40.04.10.0.bin to .\device_test\images\Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.0.img...
    Image post-copy modified: 10/17/2022 12:41:45
    Adding image file .\device_test\images\Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.0.img to git...
```

Running `git status` before overwriting the file, of course, does not show the file as having been modified.

```
HEAD detached from 5a36217fa
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Device_lib/projects/keil/Device_lib.lib
    modified:   Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_fw_version/Device_fw_version_ROYAL.h
    modified:   Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_hw_config/Device_hw_config.h
    deleted:    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_out/.gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Device_major_version_ROBIN.txt
    Device_major_version_ROYAL.txt
    cppcheck-result-Devicelib.xml
    cppcheck-result-Deviceshim.xml
    doxygen/
    git_output.txt
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.0.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.1.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.2.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.3.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.0.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.1.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.2.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.3.h
    Device_lib/projects/keil/keil_log
    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/pca10100e/s112/arm5_no_packs/RTE/_nrf52820_xxaa/
    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/pca10100e/s112/arm5_no_packs/keil_log
    Device_test/images/.gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

But there are still no changes to the destination file needing to be staged after overwriting the file.

```
HEAD detached from 5a36217fa
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Device_lib/projects/keil/Device_lib.lib
    modified:   Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_fw_version/Device_fw_version_ROYAL.h
    modified:   Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_hw_config/Device_hw_config.h
    deleted:    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_out/.gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    Device_major_version_ROBIN.txt
    Device_major_version_ROYAL.txt
    cppcheck-result-Devicelib.xml
    cppcheck-result-Deviceshim.xml
    doxygen/
    git_output.txt
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.0.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.1.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.2.h
    Device_fw_version_ROBIN.3.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.0.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.1.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.2.h
    Device_fw_version_ROYAL.3.h
    Device_lib/projects/keil/keil_log
    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/pca10100e/s112/arm5_no_packs/RTE/_nrf52820_xxaa/
    Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/pca10100e/s112/arm5_no_packs/keil_log
    Device_test/images/.gitignore

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

For comparison, listing the files in .\device_test\images before overwriting shows the file as being modified at 10/17/2022  12:35 PM

```
    Directory: E:\jenkins\home\DeviceLib2_dev_src\Device_test\images


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM             14 .gitattributes                                                       
-a----        10/15/2022  10:32 AM              6 .gitignore                                                           
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM             86 commit_hash                                                          

... (list shortened)

-a----        10/15/2022  10:27 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.0.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:27 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.1.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:23 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.2.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:24 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.3.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:35 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.0.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:36 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.1.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:37 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.2.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:38 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.3.img                                
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.0.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.1.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.2.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.3.img
```

And shows an updated LastWriteTime of 10/17/2022  12:41 PM after overwriting.

```
    Directory: E:\jenkins\home\DeviceLib2_dev_src\Device_test\images


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM             14 .gitattributes                                                       
-a----        10/15/2022  10:32 AM              6 .gitignore                                                           
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM             86 commit_hash                                                          

... (list shortened)

-a----        10/15/2022  10:27 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.0.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:27 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.1.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:23 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.2.img                                
-a----        10/15/2022  10:24 AM          41316 Device_ROBIN_Firmware_Development.3.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:41 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.0.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:36 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.1.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:37 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.2.img                                
-a----        10/17/2022  12:38 PM          41316 Device_ROYAL_Firmware_Development.3.img                                
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.0.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.1.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.2.img                              
-a----        10/14/2022   6:51 PM          40228 Device_Whippet_Firmware_Development.3.img
```

I can go into the local repository with a command-line, manually copy the source to the destination and `git status` will correctly show the file as modified. It therefore seems to be isolated when these steps are run by Jenkins. As a starting point, I wonder if the steps taken by the Git SCM plugin in Jenkins have any influence.

```
git.exe rev-parse --resolve-git-dir localrepo\.git
git.exe config remote.origin.url git@github.com:remoterepo.git
git.exe --version
git --version
git.exe fetch --tags --progress -- git@github.com:remoterepo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/branch_name^{commit}"
git.exe config core.sparsecheckout
git.exe checkout -f 63cd0f5b1fd084291ab9f97bd3f03a4d2079101c
git.exe rev-list --no-walk b42d583949d13f5ea9de729b61ab7be81c699bb6
```

**Update:** 
To @LeGEC's recommendation, `git update-index --refresh` shows the same unstaged changes- the binary file not being shown in either case.

```
Device_lib/projects/keil/Device_lib.lib: needs update
Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_fw_version/Device_fw_version_ROYAL.h: needs update
Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_hw_config/Device_hw_config.h: needs update
Device_platforms/nordic15_2/Device_device/Device_out/.gitignore: needs update
```

Comment: Can you check if `git update-index --refresh` and `git update-index --really-refresh` have any effect ?

Comment: Both commands output the same list of files that show up as "changes not staged for commit" seen in `git status` and still does not include the binary file. I tried it both in the script right after overwriting the tracked binary file and also from command-line.

Comment: Maybe one of the many answers here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316479/7411885 . My experience is either that I need to `git rm --cached` plus `git reset` due to a busted cache, OR that I've just checked out the repo multiple times, and am in the wrong one compared to my tools...

Comment: "the script fails upon committing which I can see in the git output" : can you please add this output to your question ? (note: copy the text, no screen capture please) "I  can go into the local repository [...], *copy the binary over manually*" what do you mean by copying the binary ? shouldn't the binary already be present in that local repository ? what happens when you don't copy anything and run `git status` in the pipeline local repo ?

Comment: @LeGEC The binary is output in one location by the compiler and then copied to another folder where it is tracked.

If I run `git status` without copying manually, the binary file does not show as modified even though it was overwritten by the script.

Comment: Ok, to rule out one stupid bug : did you confirm that your script did indeed copy that binary file to the expected place ? `diff <built> <versioned>`, or compare `md5sum`, or ...

Comment: if you are looking for a hashing function and for some reason don't have easy access to `md5sum`or `sha1sum` or ..., you can also use `git hash-object` : `git hash-object <built>` vs `git hash-object <versioned>`

Comment: @LeGEC The existing file, the built file, and the versioned file all had the same hash which makes sense since I have not been changing any source code each time I test. What I did not know is that git apparently does not take the last modified time into consideration when looking for changes.

Comment: I have confirmed that when the existing versioned image has a different hash, the script copies the new build and git finds the changes in the versioned.

Comment: I don't completely understand your last comments. I'll say: git looks for differences in *content* only. If the content of a file hasn't changed, then there is no modification to commit.  Is that what was puzzling you ?

Comment: Thank you, yes that was exactly what I was confused about.