# Directories have disappeared from git repo

Tags: git

I'm having trouble with git on Windows. I've lost some directories, and others are listed as untracked in git even though they've been part of the repo.

One directory literally does not exist on my machine, but it exists in origin/master. However, running `git pull origin master` yields "`Already up-to-date.`" And `git reset --hard HEAD` doesn't change anything. My `HEAD` is the same as the origin's `HEAD`.

How do I get my directories back into my local repository? Checking out earlier commits still doesn't restore these folders. Nor does `git checkout origin/master`. I've tried creating the directory myself and `git add`ing it, but the change doesn't show up in `git status`.

I have no `.gitignore` file.

Comment: What are the directories called?

Comment: @RyPeck Not really relevant, there are quite a few... let's say `foo` and `bar` are missing but `baz` is intact.

Comment: Was there any content in the directories?

Comment: @RyPeck Yes, files and subdirectories containing files and subdirectories. Beyond that I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you have marked the directories assume unchanged by accident? Can you check with `git ls-files -v` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged)?

Comment: Do you by chance have anything in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`?

Comment: No and no. At this point I'm going to just nuke the directory, thanks for your thoughts though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in a branch before attempting any pull:

```
git branch -avv
git checkout master
```

An "Already up-to-date." generally means you are in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

You can try also to clone again your repo and check if those folders are indeed there in the new local clone

Comment: Thnaks for the suggestions. I've cloned the repo in a new location and the folders I'm expecting are all there. But in the original repo I'm definitely on branch master.

Comment: @eli any chance you could report your modifications from the first repo to the new clone? You could then add and commit there.