# Undoing git update-index --assume-unchanged

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have used the following command to add a file to the repository with some default settings, then change the settings locally without pushing them to the repo every single time:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filepath>
```

Now I need to push my local changes to the repo so I would need to undo this command. How would I be able to do this?

**Note**: I am aware that deleting the repo and then cloning it again would undo this and I have a wild guess that `git reset --hard` would also work but I have multiple files that are in the same situation and executing the above command to have git ignore them again is just not feasible. Therefore I'm looking for a command that would only affect that specific file.

Comment: FYI  `git reset --hard` does *not* undo this

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To [turn off the assume unchanged bit](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filepath>
```

Comment: also note: to get a list of all files with the assume-unchanged bit

```git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'```

(as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363197/can-i-get-a-list-of-files-marked-assume-unchanged )