# Git does not detect change in file

Tags: git

I am tracking my home dir in a repo, with lots of ignores. I have just modified my `.bashrc` and git does not realize about it. That means that:

1. `.bashrc` is being ignored: no, since it is not in the `.gitignore`
2. it is set as `assume-unchanged` (`git update-index --assume-unchanged`).  According [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2363495/647991) I can list those files, and it is not in the list.

I am out of ideas. What could be going on?

Comment: What is the location of `.bashrc` relative to the top level of the repo?  Did you check _every_ `.gitignore` file?

Comment: I am going to disappoint here, but the problem was that my .bashrc is actually a symlink to another file (which I track in another repo), and the symlink has indeed not changed.

Comment: There isn't really much to it - if the change doesn't appear, the file must be either ignored or your change is already commited. For the first case you can use `git add -A` as @phaberest pointed out in their answer and for the second case you can backup your file, do `git reset --hard` and then check if your file got reset. If it did, try adding it now.

Comment: The fact that this was a symlinked file changes things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does git handle symbolic links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/how-does-git-handle-symbolic-links)

Comment: In essence, [this particular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/1079354) may shed more light on the matter.

Comment: @Makoto: sure, but I didn't remember it was a symlink, and listing the files in the homedir is something it does not usually help because there are so many of them. So I do not usually do it, specially for hidden files. And having .bashrc be a symlink is something really strange (I do that because of historical reasons). So it was not an obvious catch. Leason learnt: if it is not ignored, and not assume-unchanged, the content has changed and git does not notice, it is probably a symlink.

Comment: Something I learn today too, nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

`git add .bashrc` should help.

If you specify the file you want to add instead of just `git add -A` will add it even if it is ignored.

Comment: Thanks. It was already added, and it was a symlink, which hasn't changed.